# Can I transfer HSA into my spouse's account?

Tags: united-states, hsa

The title says it all, my wife just quit her job and we're moving back into my insurance. Her HSA custodian charges $5/mo in service fees, which we don't want to deal with.  Can we roll her HSA into my account to avoid that fee?

We file jointly, if that matters.

Comment: Perhaps you could shop around for another custodian. If you find one you like it may be possible open a new HSA acct in her name and then roll the HSA funds to the favored account.

Answer (score 5):

No. An HSA is similar to an IRA, in that it's an individual account. I'd suggest you use hers for all expenses and make new deposits to yours until your wife's HSA is depleted.

Answer (score 4):

You can't roll her HSA account into yours, but you can roll her HSA account into another HSA account that is hers.

A $5 per month fee for an HSA account is ridiculous. Find another account that has no fees, and move the money there. I suggest talking to your local credit union.